# inserir dados com ajax e switch em php

Tags: php, ajax, case

Tenho um *script php* que utilizo *GET* para pegar um parâmetro da *url* e passar para um *switch php* e executar uma determinada função.

Esse *script* funciona perfeito sem erros mas como utilizar ele com *ajax*??

Quando chamo o *ajax* com a *url*

*url*: `cor.php`, (arquivo sem *switch*) ele grava os dados perfeitamente mas quando o *ajax* chama

*url*: `cor.php?acao=inserir`, (neste caso, eu chamaria o arquivo php com *switch*) ele apresenta erro e não prossegue, ele nao acha a função switch

Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

Estrutura do switch:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['id_usuario'])){
    echo "Acesso negado!";
    exit;
}else{
    include "conexao.php";

    $id = (int)$_GET["id"];
    $acao = $_GET['acao'];

    switch ($acao) {


        case alterar:


        break;

        case excluir:


        break;

        case bloquear:



        case ativar:


        break;


        case cadastroCor:


        break;

    }}
    ?>
```

Comment: Se você está falando do _switch_ do _PHP_, é melhor editar essa pergunta e mostrar o _script_ que apresenta o erro.

Comment: Por favor, precisamos do código para te ajudar - ou pelo menos parte dele.

Comment: amigos , se vocês sabem oque é ajax e switch em php, o código não é necessário, so presiso saber como fazer o ajax chamar uma função switch do arquivo php e passar os dados para ela

Comment: Sem a correta postagem do seu codigo, fica difícil te ajudar, o switch case que você postou por exemplo esta tratando as Strings de forma incorreta, por exemplo. Poste o código php e o da sua view para ser analisada.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
url:'cor.php', data : {acao:'inserir'}, dataType : 'GET'
})
.done(function (retorno) {
//
});
```

Nesse caso o acao é como está escrito a variável no código PhP.

Comment: e tentei deste jeito mas não deu certo. com o arquivo sem switch ele funciona perfeito

Comment: Manda a estrutura do seu switch pra gente ver como ta..

Quanto ao JS ficaria:



$.ajax({
   url: 'url do destino',
   method: 'POST',
   data: 'acao=inserir&' . $('form[name="nome"]').serialize(),
   beforeSend: function(){
     //Se voce quiser dar alguma coisa para o usuario enquanto realiza o processo
   },
   success: function(data){
     console.log(data);
   }
});

Comment: Esse ação está sendo passado como? No método como ele está?

Comment: @MarcusMaciel  esta ai a estrutura do switch , marcus , irei testar deste jeito que voce disse

Comment: @HerbertJunior postei a estrutura do switch para voce da uma olhada

Comment: Certo, e o erro que ele da ? Ele exibe o valor nulo?

Comment: @HerbertJunior nao chega a carregar nenhum switch em o script para quando chega no php

Comment: Usa o Chrome em modo desenvolvedor, apertando F12 e olha se não dá erro 404 ou algo do tipo ... Pode ser que o problema seja na hora de chamar o método ...